# Apple LLVM 4.2, list of available __attribute__(()) for Objective-C

Tags: xcode, llvm

I'm looking for a list of available `__attribute__(())` directives and I cannot find them. I only know `__attribute__((objc_requires_super))`.

I swear I searched and searched and I did not find anything. Maybe I'm missing some term to include in my search.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 7):

The docs can sometimes fall behind. For a complete list, there is no more up-to-date place to go than the source code!

https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/include/clang/Basic/Attr.td

Here's an example:

```
def Visibility : InheritableAttr {
  let Clone = 0;
  let Spellings = [GNU<"visibility">, CXX11<"gnu", "visibility">];
  let Args = [EnumArgument<"Visibility", "VisibilityType",
                           ["default", "hidden", "internal", "protected"],
                           ["Default", "Hidden", "Hidden", "Protected"]>];
}
```

Here we can see how it is defined in GNU and CXX11 GNU. It also shows the valid arguments in this case (default, hidden, internal, protected).

Answer (score 4):

I found the info you need inside del llvm.org site
You can look this link: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#objective-c-features

Comment: Thanks Giuseppe, I already visited that page before but there is nothing about `objc_requires_super`. That makes me think there are more directives than the ones listed there.